# Forcing matrix equation to fit inside the margins

Tags: equations, align, matrices

I have the following matrix equation. However, the equation doesnt perfecty fit inside one line. The matrix goes right over the edge but also doesnt start at 0cm at the left. Does someone has one idea how to achieve the matrix to fit inside the equation ?

Here is a short MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=40mm,right=30mm,top=30mm,bottom=35mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\noindent Dem ..... zu Folge, kann jede der $k$ Dimensionen aus Gleichung () einzeln regressiert werden. Bei Annahme zentrierter Daten ergibt sich
\begin{flalign*}
 &\begin{bmatrix}
y_{p+1,i} \\
y_{p+2,i}  \\
\vdots \\
\vdots \\
y_{T,i}
\end{bmatrix} =
 \begin{bmatrix}
y_{p,1} & \cdots & y_{p,k} & \cdots & \cdots & y_{1,1} & \cdots & y_{1,k}  \\
y_{p+1,1} & \cdots & y_{p+1,k} & \cdots & \cdots & y_{2,1} & \cdots & y_{2,k}    \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  \\
y_{T-1,1} & \cdots & y_{T-1,k} & \cdots & \cdots & y_{T-p,1} & \cdots & y_{T-p,k}  
\end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
\Phi_{1,1,i} \\
\Phi_{1,2,i}  \\
\vdots \\
\vdots \\
\Phi_{p,k,i}
\end{bmatrix} +
 \begin{bmatrix}
\varepsilon_{p+1,i} \\
\varepsilon_{p+2,i}  \\
\vdots \\
\vdots \\
\varepsilon_{T,i}
\end{bmatrix}, &
\end{flalign*}
für $i=1,\dots,k$. Mit $\mathbb{Z}$ als Lagmatrix gilt für die $i$-te Dimension äquivalent
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the larger matrix you have two columns of dots. With one column the equation fits. Or you might need to break the equation on two lines.

Comment: I used the two columns of dots to show that the distance between the cells is larger

Comment: Can I somehow reduce the space on the left. There is a  bit of space that can be used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `flalign*` to begin with; using just `equation*` will reduce the amount of overfilling. With `flalign*` I get an overfull of 30.88466pt, with `equation*` it is 14.19312pt.

Next, you can avoid the double columns and rows of dots and, if you wish, decrease the amount of padding between columns. Do it locally, so only the big matrix will be affected.

Without decreasing `\arraycolsep` the overfull is a mere 1.93335pt, which could also be cured by inserting `\!\!` after the big matrix. However, reducing `\arraycolsep` by 2pt will make the display much shorter and better.

I also add a trick for lowering the subscripts (add an empty superscript), which improves the appearance of the capital letter subscripts.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % mandatory for German
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=40mm,right=30mm,top=30mm,bottom=35mm]{geometry}

\newcommand{\evdots}{\hspace*{0.25em}\vdots\hspace*{0.25em}}

\begin{document}
\noindent Dem ..... zu Folge, kann jede der $k$ Dimensionen aus Gleichung () einzeln regressiert werden. Bei Annahme zentrierter Daten ergibt sich
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
y^{}_{p+1,i} \\
y^{}_{p+2,i}  \\
\vdots \\
y^{}_{T,i}
\end{bmatrix} =
\begingroup\addtolength{\arraycolsep}{-2pt}
\begin{bmatrix}
y^{}_{p,1} & \dots & y^{}_{p,k} & \hdotsfor{2} & y^{}_{1,1} & \dots & y^{}_{1,k}  \\
y^{}_{p+1,1} & \dots & y^{}_{p+1,k} & \hdotsfor{2} & y^{}_{2,1} & \dots & y^{}_{2,k}    \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \evdots & \evdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  \\
y^{}_{T-1,1} & \dots & y^{}_{T-1,k} & \hdotsfor{2} & y^{}_{T-p,1} & \dots & y^{}_{T-p,k}  
\end{bmatrix}
\endgroup
\begin{bmatrix}
\Phi_{1,1,i} \\
\Phi_{1,2,i}  \\
\vdots \\
\Phi_{p,k,i}
\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix}
\varepsilon^{}_{p+1,i} \\
\varepsilon^{}_{p+2,i}  \\
\vdots \\
\varepsilon^{}_{T,i}
\end{bmatrix}, 
\end{equation*}
für $i=1,\dots,k$. Mit $\mathbb{Z}$ als Lagmatrix gilt für die $i$-te Dimension äquivalent
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You simply can play with the value of `\arraycolsep` (locally): setting it to 4pt, instead of 5, is enough. I took the opportunity to  add some improvements to your matrices (at least from my point of view):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=40mm,right=30mm,top=30mm,bottom=35mm, showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent Dem ..... zu Folge, kann jede der $k$ Dimensionen aus Gleichung () einzeln regressiert werden. Bei Annahme zentrierter Daten ergibt sich
\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{4pt}
 \begin{bmatrix}
y_{p+1,i} \\
y_{p+2,i} \\
\vdots \\[-1.5ex]
\vdots \\[-1ex]
y_{T,i}
\end{bmatrix} =
 \begin{bmatrix}
y_{p,1} & \cdots & y_{p,k} & \hdotsfor{2} & y_{1,1} & \cdots & y_{1,k} \\
y_{p+1,1} & \cdots & y_{p+1,k} & \hdotsfor{2} & y_{2,1} & \cdots & y_{2,k} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\vdots} & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\[-1.5ex]
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\vdots} & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\[-1ex]
y_{T-1,1} & \cdots & y_{T-1,k} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ldots\ldots} & y_{T-p,1} & \cdots & y_{T-p,k}
\end{bmatrix}%
 \begin{bmatrix}
\Phi_{1,1,i} \\
\Phi_{1,2,i} \\
\vdots \\[-1.5ex]
\vdots \\[-1ex]
\Phi_{p,k,i}
\end{bmatrix} +
 \begin{bmatrix}
\varepsilon_{p+1,i} \\
\varepsilon_{p+2,i} \\
\vdots \\[-1.5ex]
\vdots \\[-1ex]
\varepsilon_{T,i}
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation*}
für $i=1,\dots,k$. Mit $\mathbb{Z}$ als Lagmatrix gilt für die $i$-te Dimension äquivalent

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @egreg: You're right. I had already done it, but I copied an initial version. I'll fix it at once.